# string/double conversion for console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm having some difficulties trying to figure out how to successfully add the "daysPast" in the foreach/if loop as a double. It is currently a string and the alert is asking for a double. The code itself functions as a file/directory deleter that is set to certain number of days. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FilePath" value="C:\testFolder\" /><!--root folder -->
    <add key="TimeSpan" value="-14 days"/><!--adjust days  -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //number of days from App.config
    String daysPast = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeSpan"];

    String path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];

    // Reference to a directory.
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    // Reference to each directory in that directory.
    DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();

    //StreamWriter file name
    string fileName = "fileResults_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm") + ".txt";

    try
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in diArr)
        {
            if (dir.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysPast))
                Directory.Delete(dir.FullName, true);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("File(s) deleted on: " + DateTime.Now);
                sw.WriteLine("============================================");
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine(fileName);
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine("End of list");
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an issue, please try again.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `int.TryParse()` or `double.TryParse()` ?

Comment: You're going to have to split that up into the numeric part and the units and "parse" them separately. It would be easier from a coding perspective to stringify/parse a `TimeSpan`, then create the "-14 days" string at runtime based on the value of the `TimeSpan`. But if you need the config to be edited by hand, you may have to do the extra work depending on what kind of users you have: `<add key="TimeSpan" value="-14.00:00:00"/>` is reasonable for some, less so for others. Where I work, I'd do that and comment it, and if That One Guy has trouble, well, he will anyway.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - Thank you, I appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up replacing the "DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysPast)", with "DateTime.Parse(daysPast)":

```
 try
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in diArr)
        {
            if (dir.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Parse(daysPast))
                Directory.Delete(dir.FullName, true);


            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("File(s) deleted on: " + DateTime.Now);
                sw.WriteLine("============================================");
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine(dir);
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine("End of list");
                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```